# How to access the resource via key defined in generic.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Current I am using `Generic.xaml` and defined a custom class instance in it. Like below:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/TextPicker;component/Themes/FiltersTreeView.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in `FiltersTreeView.xaml` I define an instance of my cutomized UI class.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:TextPicker.Utils"
                    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:TextPicker.Commands"
                    xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:TextPicker.CustomControls"
                    xmlns:dm="clr-namespace:TextPicker.Models">

    <cc:ColorPiePopup x:Key="colorPiePopup"/>
    ....
<ResourceDictionary/>
```

And now, I try to use `Application.Current.FindResource` to find it, but it always return `null`.

So how can I get this resource defined from `Generic.xaml`? I mean using code.

Comment: Did you add the _Generic.xaml_ as `ResourceDictionary` in the _App.xaml_?

Comment: I have ThemeInfo:: ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly in AssemblyInfo.as, is it enough? I check the App.xaml, currently the Generic.xaml does not in it, but Generic.xaml indeed works, because the other style setting in it apply to my control.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50961498/5525302):

> You can not access the resource in generic.xaml in your app directly.
> [...]
> So if you want to use the resource in the generic.xaml, you should add it as a general ResourceDictionary in your app